# Adding a custom attribute to link

Tags: visualforce

Our modal link has a custom attribute (data-open-modal) that triggers the modal to open.

Example

```
<a href="#example-modal-2" class="button" aria-controls="example-modal-2" data-open-modal>Open large modal</a>
```

However, VF pages does not allow empty attributes to be added. I've been looking at docs and came across adding [custom HTML attributes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_html_features_pass_through_attributes.htm) to code but however, I'm not entirely sure if this is the correct approach for adding in my custom attribute to my links. Is the below code acceptable? Is there another better way to add an attribute to my link?

```
<apex:outputText value="data-open-modal" />

<a href="#example-modal-2" class="usa-button" aria-controls="example-modal-2" <apex:outputText value="data-open-modal" />>Open large modal</a>
```

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE).

Answer (score 0):

If it's simply about detecting the presence of the attribute, just put in any arbitrary value:

```
<a ... data-open-modal="true">...
```

CSS and JavaScript both don't have a problem with dealing with these:

```
[data-open-modal] {
  color: red;
}
```

...

```
document.querySelectorAll('[data-open-modal]')
```

... etc

Comment: We tried that first approach, data-open-modal="true" and that didn't render correctly. The attribute needs to be by itself with no values associated with it in link.

Comment: @PaulH That's an odd requirement. Is this part of a library that requires this? As a very "ugly" hack, you could use the [document.write](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) trick to slide this attribute in while rendering the page.

Comment: Yup. Not sure if that document.write will work for us. Trying to see if there is a more cleaner way to accomplish this but thanks for the suggestion!